# i am registering user using inbuilt "User" models but user's data is not displaying in "ADMIN panel" why

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

views.py in auth_system app

[veiw.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dql09.png)

urls.py in project
[project urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AuPR.png)

urls.py in app

registration form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Gdw.png)

i am trying to add users using django built in models "User" i have created a registration view in views.py and saving data in User no error is showing.

while clickin on submit button page is redirecting to newpage and when i go to check in admin panel the data is not showing there is no user to display only one user which was created using command - python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Avoid using images of text. Ref: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Your registration form has an action of

```
action="{% url 'login_page' %}"
```

However, your registraton form handling is on your registration view.

You need to point the form to the correct page for the form to be handled correctly.